# Mysql connection in php

Tags: php, mysqli

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

This is the error I am getting trying to connect MySQL with my php application

I removed the semicolon from extension=MySQL in php.ini file but still doesn't work

Comment: You'll likely need to restart your web server's service.

Comment: @JNevill Hi already did that

Comment: Are there any other debug steps you've performed? Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: @JNevill No sir i havent

Comment: What OS are you on? Can you copy/paste the exact line in your `php.ini` (I'm thinking it may be a difference between `mysql` and `mysqli`, where the latter is the newer extension).

Comment: @JNevill windows and the extension is mysql sir

Comment: In the php.ini on windows, I think there should be a line like `extension=php_mysqli.dll`. Note that the `i` is important since you are using `mysqli_connect()` (which is a good choice). After finding and uncommenting that line, restart your web server service once again and see if you get past that error.

Comment: The line may also lack the `.dll` and just be `extension=mysqli`.

Comment: @JNevill okay sir will try this out